# Unitary-transformation invariant measure on subset of the sphere

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

It is stated as a fact in [this correction paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/301644588.pdf) that

> if $A$ is a subspace [and $U(A)$ is the set of unit vectors in $A$] then there is a unique probability measure defined on $U (A)$ which is invariant under any unitary transformation of $A$, which we call the uniform distribution on $U(A)$

Could anyone point me to a resource elaborating on this? This is mainly a graph theory paper which I am trying to digest, but I haven't taken a course in measure theory. I would like to know how to construct this measure/what it looks like.

Comment: Since you are working with $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$, it is just the usual $(\dim A)-1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure suitably normalised, or equivalently, you can think of it as the $\dim A$-dimensional volume of the cone normalized by the volume of the $\dim A$-dimensional ball.  This result is false if we work with infinite-dimensional $A$s (you need to loosen the strict unitary/orthogonal invariance, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach to constructing such a measure. $A$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^k$ for some $k$, so we can identify $U(A)$ with the unit sphere $S^{k - 1} \subset \mathbb{R}^k$. $S^{k - 1}$ is a $C^1$ $k - 1$ dimensional surface, so there is the natural surface measure $\nu$ on $S^{k - 1}$ such that if $O \subset \mathbb{R}^{k - 1}$ is open and $\phi \colon O \to U \subset S^{k - 1}$ is a coordinate chart, then for any Borel measurable $f \colon S^{k - 1} \to [0, \infty]$,
$$\int_{U}f(y)\,d\nu(y) = \int_{O}f(\phi(x))\sqrt{g(x)}\,dx,$$
where $g(x) = \det(D\phi(x)^*D\phi(x))$. It is not difficult to deduce from the above formula that $\nu$ is invariant under unitary transformations. The desired probability measure would be $\nu' = \frac{1}{\nu(S^{k - 1})}\nu$.